# Giving access to PHP to write and read from log directory while blocking public access to it

Tags: php, permissions

I have a log directory which is located in the root directory of my PHP project. There are 2 log files in this directory: `actions.log` and `error.log`

```
log
|_actions.log
|_error.log
```

I am trying to give access to PHP to be able to write to and read from this directory. As I am using Apache as my webserver, I give the ownership of the folder to www-data

```
sudo CHOWN -R www-data:www-data log
```

and then I set the permissions to `drwxr--r--`. So PHP can write to and read from the file. But the problem is that, with this method, the log directory is publicly accessible.
Is it possiblle to restrict access without using `.htaccess` file or moving the log directory out of root directory?

Comment: Save the logs outside of the website folder structure.  They won't be publically accessible if there's no URL that maps to them.

Comment: @David, actually the question was, without moving the log directory out of root directory.

Comment: Is there a reason to not use `.htaccess`?

Comment: @Chris, if deleted accidentally, the folder will be public. If there's no other options then I will go for moving the folder out of root.